# Handling Null being thrown by Library Method?

Tags: java, string, validation, nullpointerexception, null

I have the below code where I am trying to handle a null pointer being thrown, but even if it is null I still get the null error.

How can I handle the null pointer and return an empty String most efficently when `LibraryMethod.getValue` is null?

```
private static String createValue(NodeList userAttributes) {

            if(null != LibraryMethod.getValue(LibraryMethod.getNode(userAttributes, USER_NAMES).get())){
                return LibraryMethod.getValue(LibraryMethod.getNode(userAttributes, USER_NAMES).get());
            }

            return EMPTY_STRING;
        }
```

Comment: What is `LibraryMethod`? Is that something you wrote? Also, this code doesn't throw null or null pointer - it throws NullPointerException (presumably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of patterns for solving this type of problem.

1. the library exposing the `get(xyz)` method can also expose a `has(xyz)` method:

   ```
   if (lib.has(xyz)) {
       return lib.get(xyz);
   }

   return 0;
   ```
2. the library exposing `get(xyz)` can also expose `get(xyz, defaultval)`:

   ```
   return lib.get(xyz, 0);
   ```
3. some programming languages support an optional chaining syntax, for example:

   ```
   return user?.address?.street;
   ```
4. Use some kind of exception interface, for example:

   ```
   try {
       result = lib.get(xyz);
   } catch (NoSuchKeyException e) {
       result = 0;
   }
   ```

Related to option #3, Java has a notion of [Optional](https://stackify.com/optional-java/), which you might want to look at.